# html 5 canvas drawing error

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm trying to build my first nearly-complex map based on vectors drawn in a html 5 canvas.

It works well, except the scaling. I noticed the following:

- In Firefox everything works well (except the mousewheel, but thats just for testing)
- In Chrome zooming out with the mousewheel to a scale factor < 1 it appears like the image gets duplicated every time its drawn
- In Android and iOS, using zoom gesture, there's the biggest problems: every time the image is repainted there are duplicated images.

I thought at first it's my fault, maybe the canvas doesn't get cleared. But after some testing, the "ghosts" disappear and new ghosts appear.

It would be so cool if someone could help.

Code - HTML:

```
<div>
    <div style="position:absolute;top:30px;z-index:102;">
        <canvas id="canvas" width="1386" height="747" style="position:absolute;"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div style="position:absolute; top:30px;" id="debugText">Debug</div>
    <div style="position:absolute;top:30px; visibility: hidden;">
        <canvas id="debugCanvas" width="1386" height="747"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div style="position:absolute; left: 200px;z-index:99;" id="debugContols">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="#" onClick="javascript:zoomIn(0, 0, 0.5);">Zoom 0.5</a>
        <a href="#" onClick="javascript:zoomIn(0, 0, 2);">Zoom 2</a>
        <a href="#" onClick="javascript:zoomIn(0, 0, 3);">Zoom 3</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Code - Javascript:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var debugCanvas = document.getElementById("debugCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var ctxDebug = debugCanvas.getContext("2d");
var context = ctx;
var scale = 1;
var originx = 0;
var originy = 0;

function draw() {
    // plne/Straen
[find drawing in fiddle, since its too long]
}

this.onmousewheel = function(event) {
    var mousex = event.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
    var mousey = event.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
    var wheel = event.wheelDelta/120;//n or -n

    //according to Chris comment
    var zoom = Math.pow(1 + Math.abs(wheel)/2 , wheel > 0 ? 1 : -1);

    zoomIn(mousex, mousey, zoom);
    return;
}

var isZooming = false;
var distances = new Array();

function touchStart(e) {
    preventDefaultScroll(e);
    if(e.touches.length > 1 && isZooming == false) {
        var touch1 = event.touches[0];
        var touch2 = event.touches[1];

        x1 = touch1.pageX;
        y1 = touch1.pageY;
        x2 = touch2.pageX;
        y2 = touch2.pageY;

        var diffX = x2 - x1;
        var diffY = y2 - y1;

        var centerX = x1 + diffX/2;
        var centerY = y1 + diffY/2;

        //$("#debugText").text(centerX + " " + centerY);
        debugCanvas.width = debugCanvas.width;
        ctxDebug.beginPath();
        ctxDebug.arc(centerX, centerY, 20, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        ctxDebug.fillStyle = 'green';
        ctxDebug.fill();
        ctxDebug.lineWidth = 5;
        ctxDebug.strokeStyle = '#003300';
        ctxDebug.stroke();

        zoomCenterX = centerX;
        zoomCenterY = centerY;

        var touch1 = event.touches[0];
        var touch2 = event.touches[1];

        x1 = touch1.pageX;
        y1 = touch1.pageY;
        x2 = touch2.pageX;
        y2 = touch2.pageY;

        var distanz = dist(x1,y1,x2,y2);
        lastDistance = distanz;

        distanceInterval = setInterval(checkDistance,50);
        isZooming = true;
    }
}

    var distanceInterval;
    var zoomCenterX;
    var zoomCenterY;
    var lastDistance = 0;
    function checkDistance()
    {
    $("#debugText").text("checkDist");
        if(distances.length == 0) return;





        var distanceGesamt = 0;

        for(var i = 0; i < distances.length; i++)
        {
            distanceGesamt += distances[i];
        }


        var distanceDurchschnitt = distanceGesamt / distances.length;


        var curDist = distanceDurchschnitt - lastDistance;

        var zoomFac = 1 + (curDist / 100);

        $("#debugText").text(distanceDurchschnitt + " " + zoomFac);

        distances = new Array();


        zoomIn(zoomCenterX, zoomCenterY, zoomFac)
        lastDistance = distanceDurchschnitt;
    }

    function touchEnd(e)
    {
        if(e.touches.length < 2)
        {
            isZooming = false;
            clearInterval(distanceInterval);

        }
    }

    function dist(x1,y1,x2,y2)
     {
        return Math.sqrt((x1 -= x2) * x1 + (y1 -= y2) * y1);
     }

    function touchMove(e)
    {
        if(isZooming)
        {
            var touch1 = event.touches[0];
            var touch2 = event.touches[1];

            x1 = touch1.pageX;
            y1 = touch1.pageY;
            x2 = touch2.pageX;
            y2 = touch2.pageY;

            var distanz = dist(x1,y1,x2,y2);
            distances.push(distanz);
        }
    }

    function preventDefaultScroll(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        window.scroll(0,0);
        return false;
    } 



    canvas.addEventListener('gestureend', function(e) {
        if (e.scale < 1.0) {
            // User moved fingers closer together
        } else if (e.scale > 1.0) {
            // User moved fingers further apart
        }
    }, false);

    function zoomIn(mousex, mousey, zoom)
    {

        canvas.style.display = 'none';
        context.translate(
            originx,
            originy
        );
        context.scale(zoom,zoom);
        context.translate(
            -( mousex / scale + originx - mousex / ( scale * zoom ) ),
            -( mousey / scale + originy - mousey / ( scale * zoom ) )
        );

        originx = ( mousex / scale + originx - mousex / ( scale * zoom ) );
        originy = ( mousey / scale + originy - mousey / ( scale * zoom ) );
        scale *= zoom;





         requestAnimFrame(function() {
            context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
              draw();
        });


        canvas.style.display = 'block';
        //context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        draw();
        addEventListener('touchstart', touchStart, true);
        addEventListener('touchmove', touchMove, true);
        addEventListener('touchend', touchEnd, true);
        addEventListener('touchcancel', touchEnd, true);


    });
    window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
      return  window.requestAnimationFrame       ||
              window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
              window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
              function( callback ){
                window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
              };
    })();
```

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AWeyr/)

Comment: I noted that if I add canvas.width = canvas.width before redrawing it works better... But I think this can't be solution...

Comment: It is, you need to clear the canvas before redrawing, otherwise, if the new image doesn't cover the old, the old image won't be cleared off. Another way would just be `context.clearRect(0,0,width,height);`

Answer (score 5):

Okay, so the first problem I found in your code was that you were using `context` instead of `ctx` when you were doing context transforms, so I fixed that.

Next, I moved the `clearRect` to the top of the function, and then drew after the context was already transformed.

Finally, there was a little bit of map still duplicating at the bottom, so I changed `clearRect` to clear twice the actual height of the canvas `canvas.height*2`.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AWeyr/8/)

Comment: thank you so much! Couldn't try it on android yet, but on iPhone it looks pretty well. Question is, why do you have to clear canvas.height*2. Could it be that this is because of the zooming? And that canvas.height*currentScaleFactor should be cleared?

Comment: I would not use `canvas.height*currentScaleFacter` because you sometimes draw the zoomed out map in the middle of the canvas as opposed to the tip-top, so not all the map would be erased, which brings me to my next point.

Since your map is larger than your canvas itself, portions of the map are drawn outside the canvas so you have to make sure to clear that off. You DON'T necessarily have to use `canvas.height*2` but it should be enough to clear that excess part off.

Answer (score 3):

Two thoughts:

First: Wow, nice use of paths to lay out a map--very extensive!

Second: Since you're driving your zooming with scrollwheel/touch rather than mouseclicks, you need to remove the requestAnimFrame animation.

The animation was meant to gradually zoom to the point where the user mouseclicked.